# Problems of different domain with flash

Tags: javascript, flash

I don't know which title I should use for this question.

I have a webpage (e.g. index.html) which contains flash content, url:
http://www.abc.com/travel/sg/traffic/

After I finish the webpage and upload onto the staging server, the customers said that they may need to use different domain to go to the site, e.g.
http://sg.travel.com/

The images or hyperlink do not work because of this. To handle this, I try to use the base tag as follows:

```
<base href="http://www.abc.com/travel/sg/traffic/" />
```

The images and hyperlink work. However, flash file cannot call javascript afterwards.

I would like to know how I can fix the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure all the javascript is loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using relative links in the flash file? Try passing the url as a parameter and prepend the links in the flash file with them. You may also need to set up a proper `crossdomain.xml` to allow your flash to access other domains.

Answer (score 0):

if images are the same domain as the swf, you can use relative paths.
try with
`"/images/foo.png"` instead of `"http://www.abc.com/travel/sg/traffic/images/foo.png"`